# How to make a pandas DataFrame from a PISA interface list

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, dataframe, bioinformatics

I am trying to make a DataFrame in pandas from the interface results page at the [PISA server](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe/pisa/).

After clicking the `LaunchPDBePisa` button, I click on the `Interfaces` button to get a page with a table with the results I would like to parse. I am trying the following code…

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate
url_1 = 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/msd-srv/prot_int/cgi-bin/piserver'
r = requests.get(url_1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all(class_='data-table')
print table

'and also:'
table = soup.find_all(class_='data-table tborder')
print table
```

…But in both cases I get the empty list. Can I somehow get the valid URL of the query and transform it to DataFrame. This server offers the possibility of downloading XML page which can be transformed to DataFrame but it does not contain all the results I need.

Comment: For which PDB entry would you like to see the interfaces? For that PDB entry, what is/are the nummer(s) of the interface(s) that you would like to turn into a DataFrame. Can you add your expected output from the DataFrame?

Comment: I need to parse the HTML page that I get when I enter a PDB entry (e.g. 1ALL), and then go to the interfaces page. I want to make DataFrame with all the columns from that table so I can filter it based on the column values. But I would like to make a function that can parse multiple tables for many PDB entries. I downloaded 20 HTML pages for 20 PDB entries with the option save as type: Webpage, Complete, to join them in a single filtered DataFrame with the Data for all 20 proteins. But some tables have 1 more column and that is why I can not join them (1B33 has ID and 1ALL not)

Answer (score 0):

I've written a script that will make a Pandas dataframe from a PISA interface list. It can take just a PDB code or it can take the text copied from the page. The script is available [here](https://github.com/fomightez/structurework/tree/master/pdbepisa-utilities).

You can work through a series of Jupyter notebooks right in your browser demonstrating use of it by going [here](https://github.com/fomightez/pdbepisa-binder) and pressing `launch binder`. Then stepping through first few notebooks and looking for any other pertinent ones on the list. (The one listed there under 'Technical' as 'Single notebook converting a variety of formats of interface lists/reports to test handling by pisa_interface_list_to_df.py' can be considered the 'Quick Start' for those familiar with Jupyter/Python.) The idea is that the launches from there served via MyBinder.org already have all the necessary dependencies in the environment, and the notebooks can then be run to understand what is needed as input and see what to expect as output. Then you can adapt the same Jupyter notebooks and associated files, or just the code/content from them, to run the script on the PDB files in which you are interested. Launches via MyBinder.org are **temporary sessions though**, and so download to your local computer anything generated that is useful.

Those demonstrations notebooks show the script can run on the command line or be run by importing the main function of the script into other Python code.

##### Direct links:

- [script `pisa_interface_list_to_df.py` and description](https://github.com/fomightez/structurework/tree/master/pdbepisa-utilities)
- [a series of Jupyter notebooks served in active form via MyBinder](https://github.com/fomightez/pdbepisa-binder)